# RSS feed with specific keyword

Tags: wp-query, actions, rss, pre-get-posts

I am able to get articles as RSS feed from below url

```
http://wordpress_site/blog/feed
```

I am also able to get articles from BlogSpot with specific keywords as below

```
https://www.yourblogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?q=KEYWORD
```

I have tried to get articles from filtering with specific KEYWORD in wordpress blog but I am not able to get. What can be the URL.

I am very much newbie to wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the list of posts displayed in feed using [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action. And to target only feeds, you can use [`is_feed`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) conditional tag.

So such code can look like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_feed() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( isset($_GET['q']) && trim($_GET['q']) ) {
            $query->set( 's', trim($_GET['q']) );
        }
    }
} );
```

This way you can go to `example.com/feed/?q=KEYWORD` and you'll get filtered feed (be careful - most browsers are caching feeds, so you'll have to force them to refresh it).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how we can use the builtin public query parameters on feeds:

**Query parameter: `s`**

We can use the `s` query parameter on the feed:

```
https://example.com/feed/?s=KEYWORD
```

This will generate a feed for the keyword on all *searchable post types*.

**Query parameter: `post_type`**

We can restrict it to a given *post type* with:

```
https://example.com/feed/?s=KEYWORD&post_type=post
```

**Query parameter: `exact`**

We can also use the `exact` query search parameter to exactly match the search keyword (no wildcard):

```
https://example.com/feed/?s=hello+world&post_type=post&exact=1
```

**Query parameter: `sentence`**

The `sentence` query search parameter can be used to match the whole keyword sentence (no word split):

```
https://example.com/feed/?s=hello+world&post_type=post&sentence=1
```

**All together:**

```
https://example.com/feed/?s=hello+world&post_type=post&exact=1&sentence=1
```

Comment: Perfect examples